# r conditional wide to long with column name pattern

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, melt, data-transform

This is a slightly tricky dataset where the columns are laid out like this.

```
ID   C.Date      T.Date      C(Area)   T(Area)    Level(closet)_1   Venti_1    Level(closet)_2   Venti_2
733  2013.06.18  2013.06.18  65.2      42.1       C6                0          C3                1
537  2015.10.01  2015.15.01  34.5      27.2       C3                0          T11               0
909  2016-01-14  2016-01-14  15.1      25.9       T4                1          T2                1
```

Rule

```
Step1 :  Consider columns: ID, C.Date, C(Area), Level(closet)_1, Venti_1, Level(closet)_2, Venti_2
         Rearrange the data like this.

         ID  Index   Date       Ref.Level   Area    Level(closet)    Venti
         733 1       2013.06.18 C           65.2    C6                0 
         733 2       2013.06.18 C           65.2    C3                1 

Step2 :  Consider columns: ID, T.Date, T(Area), Level(closet)_1, Venti_1, Level(closet)_2, Venti_2
         Rearrange the data like this.

         ID  Index   Date       Ref.Level   Area    Level(closet)    Venti
         733 3       2013.06.18 T           42.1    NA                NA
```

Notice both Step1 and Step2 references values in columns `Level(closet)_1, Venti_1, Level(closet)_2, Venti_2`. The difference is in Step2, when there are values for `T.Date` and `T(Area)` the expectation is that either one of the `Level(closet)` value will start with `T*`, in the 1st ID 733 there were NONE. So the transformed dataset 3rd row has values NA for columns `Level(closet), Venti`. The 2nd ID 537 again has both `T.Date` and `T(Area)` values, again based on the Step2 we look for `Level(closet)` column values that start with `T*` in this case `Level(closet)_2` contains value `T11` so for the wide-to-long transformed data for ID 523 will be

Step1 :  Consider columns: ID, C.Date, C(Area), Level(closet)_1, Venti_1, Level(closet)_2, Venti_2
Rearrange the data like this.

```
     ID  Index    Date       Ref.Level   Area    Level(closet)    Venti
     537  1       2015.10.01 C           34.5    C3                0
```

Step2 :  Consider columns: ID, T.Date, T(Area), Level(closet)_1, Venti_1, Level(closet)_2, Venti_2
Rearrange the data like this.

```
     ID  Index   Date       Ref.Level   Area    Level(closet)    Venti
     537  2      2015.15.01 T           27.2    T11                0
```

The final expected dataset would look like this below

```
     ID   Index   Date       Ref.Level   Area    Level(closet)    Venti
     733  1       2013.06.18 C           65.2    C6                0 
     733  2       2013.06.18 C           65.2    C3                1 
     733  3       2013.06.18 T           42.1    NA                NA 
     537  1       2015.10.01 C           34.5    C3                0 
     537  2       2015.15.01 T           27.2    T11               0 
     909  1       2016-01-14 C           15.1    NA                NA
     909  2       2016-01-14 T           25.9    T4                1
     909  3       2016-01-14 T           25.9    T2                1
```

Sorry this is a bit complicated. On the surface level this looks like taking few rows in the wide format and reshaping this to a long format but there is a nested ifelse to see if there are any values starting with `T*` in the `Level(closet)` columns. I am completely blank how to structure this in a long format like this. Any help or suggestions is much apricated. Thanks.

---

library(tidyverse)

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~`ID`, ~`C.Date`, ~`T.Date`, ~`C(Area)`, ~`T(Area)`, ~`Level(closet)_1`, ~`Venti_1`, ~`Level(closet)_2`, ~`Venti_2`,
                "733", "2013.06.18", "2013.06.18", "65.2", "42.1", "C6", "0", "C3", "1",
                "537", "2015.10.01", "2015.15.01", "34.5", "27.2", "C3", "0", "T11", "0",
                "909", "2016-01-14", "2016-01-14", "15.1", "25.9", "T4", "1", "T2", "1"
                )
```

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of your data?

Comment: @deschen, updated the question with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works, you can follow it easily, but probably not the efficient way of doing this but does the job.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tribble(~`ID`, ~`C.Date`, ~`T.Date`, ~`C(Area)`, ~`T(Area)`, ~`Level(closet)_1`, ~`Venti_1`, ~`Level(closet)_2`, ~`Venti_2`,
                "733", "2013.06.18", "2013.06.18", "65.2", "42.1", "C6", "0", "C3", "1",
                "537", "2015.10.01", "2015.15.01", "34.5", "27.2", "C3", "0", "T11", "0",
                "909", "2016-01-14", "2016-01-14", "15.1", "25.9", "T4", "1", "T2", "1"
                ) -> df
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#>   ID    C.Date T.Date `C(Area)` `T(Area)` `Level(closet)_… Venti_1
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>            <chr>  
#> 1 733   2013.… 2013.… 65.2      42.1      C6               0      
#> 2 537   2015.… 2015.… 34.5      27.2      C3               0      
#> 3 909   2016-… 2016-… 15.1      25.9      T4               1      
#> # … with 2 more variables: `Level(closet)_2` <chr>, Venti_2 <chr>

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(1,4,5,7,9), as.numeric)) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()-> df1

df1
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#>      id c_date t_date c_area t_area level_closet_1 venti_1 level_closet_2
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1   733 2013.… 2013.…   65.2   42.1 C6                   0 C3            
#> 2   537 2015.… 2015.…   34.5   27.2 C3                   0 T11           
#> 3   909 2016-… 2016-…   15.1   25.9 T4                   1 T2            
#> # … with 1 more variable: venti_2 <dbl>
  
df1 %>% 
  select(id, c_date, c_area) -> df2

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id c_date     c_area
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1   733 2013.06.18   65.2
#> 2   537 2015.10.01   34.5
#> 3   909 2016-01-14   15.1

df1 %>% 
  select(id, t_date, t_area) -> df3

df3
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id t_date     t_area
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1   733 2013.06.18   42.1
#> 2   537 2015.15.01   27.2
#> 3   909 2016-01-14   25.9

df1 %>% 
  select(id, level_closet_1, level_closet_2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(value, "C")) %>% 
  rename(date = c_date,
         area = c_area)-> c_df
#> Joining, by = "id"

c_df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id name           value date        area
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1   733 level_closet_1 C6    2013.06.18  65.2
#> 2   733 level_closet_2 C3    2013.06.18  65.2
#> 3   537 level_closet_1 C3    2015.10.01  34.5

df1 %>% 
  select(id, level_closet_1, level_closet_2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  left_join(df3) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(value, "T")) %>% 
  rename(date = t_date,
         area = t_area) -> t_df
#> Joining, by = "id"

t_df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      id name           value date        area
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1   537 level_closet_2 T11   2015.15.01  27.2
#> 2   909 level_closet_1 T4    2016-01-14  25.9
#> 3   909 level_closet_2 T2    2016-01-14  25.9

c_df %>% 
  bind_rows(t_df) -> ct_df

ct_df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id name           value date        area
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1   733 level_closet_1 C6    2013.06.18  65.2
#> 2   733 level_closet_2 C3    2013.06.18  65.2
#> 3   537 level_closet_1 C3    2015.10.01  34.5
#> 4   537 level_closet_2 T11   2015.15.01  27.2
#> 5   909 level_closet_1 T4    2016-01-14  25.9
#> 6   909 level_closet_2 T2    2016-01-14  25.9

df1 %>% 
  select(id, level_closet_1, venti_1) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1 %>% 
              select(id, level_closet_2, venti_2)) -> df_venti

t(apply(df_venti, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))) -> df_venti[] 

df_venti
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   id    level_closet_1 venti_1 level_closet_2 venti_2
#>   <chr> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>          <chr>  
#> 1 733   C6             " 0"    <NA>           <NA>   
#> 2 537   C3             " 0"    <NA>           <NA>   
#> 3 909   T4             " 1"    <NA>           <NA>   
#> 4 733   C3             " 1"    <NA>           <NA>   
#> 5 537   T11            " 0"    <NA>           <NA>   
#> 6 909   T2             " 1"    <NA>           <NA>

df_venti %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  rename(value = level_closet_1,
         venti = venti_1) %>% 
  mutate(venti = venti %>% as.numeric(),
         id = id %>% as.numeric()) -> venti_df2

venti_df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      id value venti
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   733 C6        0
#> 2   537 C3        0
#> 3   909 T4        1
#> 4   733 C3        1
#> 5   537 T11       0
#> 6   909 T2        1

ct_df %>% 
  left_join(venti_df2) -> df_with_venti
#> Joining, by = c("id", "value")

df_with_venti
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>      id name           value date        area venti
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   733 level_closet_1 C6    2013.06.18  65.2     0
#> 2   733 level_closet_2 C3    2013.06.18  65.2     1
#> 3   537 level_closet_1 C3    2015.10.01  34.5     0
#> 4   537 level_closet_2 T11   2015.15.01  27.2     0
#> 5   909 level_closet_1 T4    2016-01-14  25.9     1
#> 6   909 level_closet_2 T2    2016-01-14  25.9     1


df_with_venti %>%
  mutate(value = value %>% str_remove_all('[0-9]+')) %>% 
  mutate(mm = 1) %>% 
  complete(id, value, fill = list(mm = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(id, value) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(mm)) %>% 
  filter(count == 0) -> missing_df
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'id' (override with `.groups` argument)

missing_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id value count
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   733 T         0
#> 2   909 C         0

missing_df %>% 
  filter(value == "C") %>% 
  pull(id) -> c_missing

c_missing
#> [1] 909

missing_df %>% 
  filter(value == "T") %>% 
  pull(id) -> t_missing 

t_missing
#> [1] 733

df1 %>% 
  filter(id %in% c_missing) %>% 
  select(id, c_date, c_area) %>% 
  rename(date = c_date,
         area = c_area) %>% 
  mutate(ref_level = "C",
         value = NA,
         venti = NA) -> c_fill_df

c_fill_df
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>      id date        area ref_level value venti
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1   909 2016-01-14  15.1 C         NA    NA

df1 %>% 
  filter(id %in% t_missing) %>% 
  select(id, t_date, t_area) %>% 
  rename(date = t_date,
         area = t_area) %>% 
  mutate(ref_level = "T",
         value = NA,
         venti = NA) -> t_fill_df

t_fill_df
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>      id date        area ref_level value venti
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1   733 2013.06.18  42.1 T         NA    NA

df_with_venti %>% 
  select(id, date, area, value, venti) %>% 
  mutate(ref_level = value %>% str_remove_all('[0-9]+')) %>% 
  bind_rows(c_fill_df) %>% 
  bind_rows(t_fill_df) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  select(id, index, date, ref_level, area, value, venti) %>% 
  rename(level_closet = value)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 7
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id index date       ref_level  area level_closet venti
#>   <dbl> <int> <chr>      <chr>     <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1   537     1 2015.10.01 C          34.5 C3               0
#> 2   537     2 2015.15.01 T          27.2 T11              0
#> 3   733     1 2013.06.18 C          65.2 C6               0
#> 4   733     2 2013.06.18 C          65.2 C3               1
#> 5   733     3 2013.06.18 T          42.1 <NA>            NA
#> 6   909     1 2016-01-14 T          25.9 T4               1
#> 7   909     2 2016-01-14 T          25.9 T2               1
#> 8   909     3 2016-01-14 C          15.1 <NA>            NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @MohanGovindasmy , the `left joins` in your solutions are creating more rows than expected. Mainly due to one-to-many situation. This is creating some problems. How do we suppose fix this part. Thanks.

Comment: @Science11 `left_join` should not create more rows, it will preserve all the rows in the original data frame and will return `NA` if the key is not present in the second data frame. I'm not able to understand which part of the code is causing the issue you mentioned. Can you please point it to me?

Comment: you are creating the `df_venti` and this does not include the date column. Then this changes to  `df_venti2`. Then you are merging this `df_venti2` with  `ct_df `. Both `df_venti2` and `ct_df` both are missing the date columns. If `left_join` is performed only based on `id` ignoring the `date`. We dont know if this merge is accurate. It is not just the `id`, the `date` column is important too. We need to make sure we are capturing the measurements for that `id` on that `date` not just blind merge based on `id`. Does this make sense ?

Comment: I borrowed heavily from your ideas and modified the code in few instances and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Science11 glad I can help. Apologise for not solving the latest issue as it was difficult to understand with the given sample data

Answer (score 1):

Suppose all columns in your dataframe are in string format for simplicity.
Then you could get the expected dataset by the following code (definitely this is not the best way though):

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(cols=c(C.Date, T.Date, `C(Area)`, `T(Area)`)) %>%
  separate(col="name", into=c("Ref.Level", "name"), sep="(\\.)|(\\()") %>%
  mutate(name=str_replace(name, "\\)", "")) %>% pivot_wider() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(`Level(closet)_1`, `Level(closet)_2`, Venti_1, Venti_2)) %>%
  separate(col="name", into=c("name", "index"), sep="_") %>% pivot_wider() %>% select(-index) %>%
  nest(data=c(`Level(closet)`, Venti)) %>% mutate(data=map2(data, Ref.Level, function(data, ref_level){
    data <- data %>% filter(str_detect(`Level(closet)`, ref_level))
    if(nrow(data)==0) data <- tibble(`Level(closet)`=NA_character_, Venti=NA_character_)
    return(data)
  })) %>% unnest(cols=data) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Index=row_number(), .after=ID) %>% ungroup(ID)
```

The trick is to first change the dataframe into very long format and nest `Level(closet), Venti` columns to filter rows.

Comment: the `pivot_wider` step gave me some headaches. The data contained some nested objects. This is largely due to reading some rows a dulpicate. Later I realized adding a line to include row.numbers would solve this problem. Thanks for the suggestion.